# python curve fit setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I am trying to use curve_fit to solve the two parameters k1, E1, but it keeps giving me the same error: setting an array element with a sequence. When I only have two arrays x and y, it works fine. Could someone tell me how to fix this problem? Thank you!

```
x = np.array([5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,
              12,12,12,12,12,12])
y = np.array([5,1,2,10,20,40,60,80,
              6,6,6,6,6,6])
z = np.array([330,330,330,330,330,330,330,330,
              330,350,370,390,410,430])
r = np.array([1.199,1.303,1.58,1.81,2.24,2.35,2.49,2.71,
                 4.3,8.0,1.4,2.32,3.4,6.24])
R = 2.5
def func(X, k1, E1):
    x, y, z = X
    return  k1 * np.exp(-E1/R/z) * x / y

#initial guess
init_guess = [1, 10000]
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, (x, y, z), r, init_guess)
print('Parameters', fittedParameters)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. I get a runtime warning, though: `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  return  k1 * np.exp(-E1/R/z) * x / y` and a result output is generated `Parameters [ 140.43789131 4269.56369374]
` What are your numpy/scipy versions? Here: 1.19.4/1.5.4